# Expected appearance for a json stringified array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to compare the values from 2 google sheets to get the difference. I'm loosely trying to follow [Javascript / Google Apps Script compare 2 arrays, return items with NO match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586001/javascript-google-apps-script-compare-2-arrays-return-items-with-no-match).

to do this I'm trying to stringify rows of my 2d value array which I created using:

```
var values = range.getValues();
```

I have created a function:

```
function toArrayOfJson(myArray){
  newArray = [];
  for(i=0; i<(myArray.length-1); i++){

    x=    myArray[i]
    Logger.log(x);
    Logger.log(myArray);
    y =JSON.stringify(myArray[i][0])

    newArray.push(JSON.stringify(myArray[i]));
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

and while debugging  I see that

```
 JSON.stringify(myArray[i])
```

takes a array that looks like:

```
 ["none", "none", "Tyler", "TX", "none" ]
```

to:

```
"["none", "none", "Tyler", "TX", "none" ]"
```

Does this look right? Is this the expected appearance for a json stringified array?

Comment: Yes, it's the expected appearance. But why are you stringifying each element, instead of just the final result?

Comment: Each element is supposed to represent 1 row and based on the link above I want to get the diff between 2 sheets that have a lot but not all rows in common . Is there a better way?

Comment: Why does that require stringifying anything? Just compare the array elements directly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: The accepted answer in the link involved doing that, so I thought maybe that would be simpler in apps script, I will check out your link ..

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't appear anywhere in the question you linked to. Are you sure that's the one you meant?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the reduce function but thought that turning each row to JSON might be an acceptable substitute .

Comment: A simple `for` loop should work fine. Loop over the two arrays, return `false` if the corresponding elements don't match. If you get to the end of the loop, return `true`.

Comment: Your approach should also work, though.